# construction joint in shear wall passing through vertical bar splices

Tags: structural-engineering

Usually in cores and shear walls, one extends vertical bars above the construction joint a distance at least equal to the lap splice length to allow for splices away from the construction joint. But is there a problem if the splice does occur at the construction joint (such that part of the splice is below and part is above the joint)?

Comment: You’ll likely need to put some more effort into this post before receiving a quality answer. You might start by updating the post with a better / more legible sketch. Also, some rough dimensions, an indication of where this section is being cut, and rough rebar size / splice length would be good. You might also ‘show your work’ by summarizing your knowledge of general construction joint placement guidelines.

Comment: I asked generally, usually in cores and shear wall I extend vertical bars above construction joint minimum lap splice length to make splice away construction joint. But if this splice location intersecting construction join ( I mean that part of splice below and part above construction joint) is there any problem

Answer (score 2):

There's no structural issue to any code that I know of. In the final state for design strength calculations construction joints are ignored.

However, it may make construction more difficult. Ask the contractor (if he's already been appointed for the project).